# What's the difference between struct mycompare and static bool mycompare?

Tags: c++

```
struct mycompare1 {
    bool operator() (const Interval a, const Interval b) {
        return a.start < b.start;
    }
} mycompare1_instance;

static bool mycompare2(const Interval a, const Interval b) {
    return a.start < b.start;
}
```

Q1: What is the difference between these two. It seems that mycompare1_instance somehow equals to mycompare2 like this. The following two lines seem to do the same thing.

```
sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), mycompare1);
sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), mycompare2);
```

Could anyone explain it?

Q2: How is "static" useful here?

Thx ahead!

Comment: You should try learning C++ from the beginnings. Your question is nonsensical.

Comment: Especially the `static` part. It's completely unrelated to the other part of the question.

Comment: And the struct part :-)

Comment: **Books:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: user3692521 - how do you know that `mycompare1_instance` is equal to `mycompare2`? Do you have some sort of code that shows it? Or do you mean one can replace the other in some situations?

Answer (score 1):

The first case defines operator() so you could could use it as a function - in short they are functors. The advantage is that it can have a state and depending how you define the operator() you could use the instance of that class as a function. Thse second case is simply a static functionn and does not hold the state in the sense of a class/struct.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the question is related to functors

ie you have seen

```
mycompare_instance1(x,y)
```

vs

```
mycompare2(x,y)
```

The first one is a functor. It used where we need to make things that are both objects with state and can be invoked like functions. The second one is a simple function